# Cucumber test fails, expectation returns true when I'm debuging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber

I'm facing a strange problem while testing using Cucumber and Rspec::Expectations.

```
within "##{@response.id}" do
  click_on "I like it"
end
expect(@response.user.reload.score).to be(55)
```

When I'm trying to run the test, it fails because of unmet expectations. But if I'm debugging this piece of code and click "I like it" button manually, expectation is met.

Comment: What if you put in your test `raiser @response.user.reload.score` and rerun your tests? Is the score equal to `55`? Is it an Integer? a String?

Comment: raise @response.user.reload.score: TypeError: exception class/object expected. Yes, while debugging, score is equal 55, but if I run test automatically, it shows 50 (liking adds 5 points to user's overall score). It is an integer value.

Comment: Is this resolved by adding a delay (`sleep 1`) before the expectation?

Comment: It doesn't help. I'm using sqlite for development and test.